# Powershell: search & replace in xlsx except first 3 columns

Tags: excel, powershell, search, replace

I need to run PS script on multiple xlsx files where I need to search and replace certain values. Script has to check entire sheet, but needs to ignore first 4 columns, aka, it has to "start" from column number 5. Is there a way how to do that with the script below please? Those first 4 columns need to be present when exporting/saving a final xlsx file. Thank you.

```
# variables
$name = "1stname"
$surname = "Surname"


# xlsx to work with
$filename =  Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.xlsx
$xldata = Import-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName "Sheet1"
$columns = $xldata[0].psobject.Properties.Name

#script
foreach ($row in $xldata) {
foreach ($cell in $columns) {
$oldvalue = $row.”$cell”
$newvalue = $oldvalue -replace $name, $surname
$row.”$cell” = $newvalue
}
}

# save xlsx file
$xldata | Export-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName “Sheet1” -ClearSheet
```

Comment: Did you consider including a column counter that increments each time the "foreach column" is passed and which will be reseted with each "foreach row" statement? Then you just have to check if the value of that variable is greater than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your second foreach loop with a [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) instead, as you'll then be able to skip the first x records as desired.

It would look like this to skip the first 4 columns:

```
# xlsx to work with
$filename = Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.xlsx
$xldata = Import-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName "Sheet1"
$columns = $xldata[0].psobject.Properties.Name
foreach ($row in $xldata) {
    for ($i = 4; $i -lt $columns.Count; $i++)
    {
        $cell = $columns[$i]
        $oldvalue = $row."$cell"
        $newvalue = $oldvalue -replace $Space, $ReplaceSpace
        $row."$cell" = $newvalue
    }
}

# save xlsx file
$xldata | Export-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -ClearSheet
```

Replace the `$i = 4` with another number if you want to start on a different column number instead.

Comment: there seem to be an issue with this operator "++" as I get this error:

_The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.Object[]'._

Comment: Strange as ***$i*** should be assigned the value 4 in for loop and will then be a number. Is $i perhaps in use elsewhere in your script that perhaps wasn't included here? Please share your updated code so that I can test from here, as my example above works when tested here.

Comment: Here you go, thanks for helping me:
_# xlsx to work with
$filename =  Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.xlsx
$xldata = Import-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName "Sheet1"
$columns = $xldata[0].psobject.Properties.Name

foreach ($row in $xldata) {
    for ($i = 4, $i -lt $columns.Count; $i++) {
        $cell = $columns[$i]
        $oldvalue = $row.”$cell”
        $newvalue = $oldvalue -replace $Space, $ReplaceSpace
        $row.”$cell” = $newvalue
    }
}

# save xlsx file
$xldata | Export-Excel -Path $filename -WorksheetName “Sheet1” -ClearSheet_

Comment: My bad, I'd incorrectly put `$i = 4,` instead of `$i = 4;` when posting above. I've updated my example. Hopefully that works for you now?

Comment: It does exactly what I need, thank you very much @NiMux. You are a superstar! :)