# powershell rename XLSX spreadsheet columns

Tags: powershell, xlsx

I have a spreadsheet that has spaces in the column names, how do I go about replacing the space with underscores on the column headers?
Note: I am new at this so bear with me
using this code with no luck:
[Powershell: search & replace in xlsx except first 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642311/powershell-search-replace-in-xlsx-except-first-3-columns)

Theo's code works great!

```
$sheetname = 'my Data'
$file      = 'C:\Users\donkeykong\Desktop\1\booka.xlsx'
# create a COM Excel object
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)
$sheet.Activate()

# get the number of columns used
$colMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# loop over the column headers and replace the whitespaces
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $header = $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value() -replace '\s+', '_'
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col) = $header
}
# close and save the changes
$workbook.Close($true)

$objExcel.Quit()
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in `Import-Excel` or in `Export-Excel` line?

Comment: Use `$filename.FullName`, in Windows PowerShell a `FileInfo` instance when coerced to string resolves to it's `.Name` property instead of `.FullName`

Comment: appreciate your assistance Santiago, the code below did the job

Comment: please don't remove the context of your question, otherwise future readers wouldn't know what your question was about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Excel file has the headers in the first row, this should work without using the ImportExcel module:

```
$sheetname = 'my Data'
$file      = 'C:\Users\donkeykong\Desktop\1\booka.xlsx'
# create a COM Excel object
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)
$sheet.Activate()

# get the number of columns used
$colMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# loop over the column headers and replace the whitespaces
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $header = $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value() -replace '\s+', '_'
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col) = $header
}
# close and save the changes
$workbook.Close($true)

$objExcel.Quit()
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Theo, appreciate so much your help, it worked!!!